# Export all the Activity history from the Lead object onto Contacts

Tags: administration

How to export all the **Activity history** from the **Lead** object onto **Contacts** ?

Can any one please suggest me the process with a detail description..

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: I need to Export all the Activity history from the Lead object onto Contacts. I have to export all the Activity history related to the Lead, do a match based on the Contact Full Name and then import then on to the Contact records. Can u please explain the process..